# Using the SQL LIKE operator with %%

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching, sql-like

I had a requirement to create a query in [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) where the search condition would include/exclude a table based on user input.

Say I have two tables, `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` with columns `KEYCOLUMN_A` and `COLUMN_A` in `TABLE_A` and columns `FKCOLUMN_B` and `COLUMN_B` in `TABLE_B`.

And a query like:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.* FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.KEYCOLUMN_A = TABLE_B.FKCOLUMN_B
AND TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%SEARCH%' AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '%SEARCH2%'
```

Now if the user does not input `SEARCH2`, I don't need to search `TABLE_B`. But this would mean an `IF ELSE` clause. And as the number of "optional" tables in the query increases, the permutations and combinations would also increase and there will be many `IF` and `ELSE` statements.

Instead I decided to keep the statement as it is. So if `SEARCH2` is empty, the query will effectively become:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.KEYCOLUMN_A = TABLE_B.FKCOLUMN_B
AND TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%SEARCH%' AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '% %'
```

Can the SQL optimizer recognize that `LIKE %%` is as good as removing the condition itself?

Comment: There is a typo in the second code sample. There should not be any space between % and %.
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.KEYCOLUMN_A = TABLE_B.FKCOLUMN_BAND TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%SEARCH%' AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '%%'

Comment: Use "sql-server" tags like 1000s of other folk...

Comment: @devanalyst: can't you edit the question to fix the typo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap an `OR` around your "B" table, such as:

```
AND (len(searchString)=0 OR table_b.column_b LIKE "%searchString%" )
```

This way, if no value for the string, its length would be zero, and the first part of the `OR` would be evaluated, always come back as true and return that portion of the equation as valid and ignore the other half using the `LIKE` clause.

You could apply the same for as many linked tables as you need.

Comment: ***searchString*** is `''` ?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you have a space in your example:

```
AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '% %'
```

That will never be optimized as it is indeed a significant condition.

Now, I think that if it is optimized away depends on the database engine and how smart it is.

For example, [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005) does offer the same execution plan for the two types of queries, while MySQL 5.0.38 does not.

Comment: There is a typo in the second code sample. There should not be any space between % and %. SELECT * FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.KEYCOLUMN_A = TABLE_B.FKCOLUMN_BAND TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%SEARCH%' AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '%%

Answer (score 2):

LIKE is used with the WHERE clause to search, update, and delete a record using wild cards.

Example:

To search all records whose employee name is starred from a character, 'a':

```
select * from Employee where Name like 'a%'
```

To update all records with name *amit* whose employee name is starting with a character, 'a':

```
update Employee set Name='amit' where Name like 'a%'
```

To delete all records whose employee name is starting with a character, 'a':

```
delete from Employee  where Name like 'a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) you can also use ILIKE, and then it's case insensitive.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite you query like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.* FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.KEYCOLUMN_A = TABLE_B.FKCOLUMN_B
AND (@paramA='' or TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%' + @paramA + '%')
AND (@paramB='' or TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '%' + @paramB + '%')
```

This way, if paramA or paramB is '', then the other column that is queried inside same parentheses will not be queried.

Comment: I think you mean the opposite. I checked the above code and it works when the condition is @paramA = '' which in effect is what DRapp's code is doing

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION and proper JOINs.

The %foo% search term is bad enough (can't use index) without adding OR and LEN to the mix too.

```
SELECT
    TABLE_A.*
FROM
    TABLE_A
    JOIN
    TABLE_B On TABLE_A.KEYCOLUMN_A = TABLE_B.FKCOLUMN_B
WHERE
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%SEARCH%' AND TABLE_B.COLUMN_B LIKE '%SEARCH2%'
UNION
SELECT
    TABLE_A.*
FROM
    TABLE_A
WHERE
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_A LIKE '%SEARCH%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column

```
LIKE '%[p-s]'  -- "It search data from table parameter where sentence ending with p,q,r,s word."
LIKE '[0-9]' --It use for search only numeric value
LIKE '%table%' -- it use for search parameter from table where use "table" keyword'.
LIKE %[^p-r]  -- it set the condition where Not Ending With a Range of Characters

Example: 
SELECT T1.BrandName,T1.BrandID,T2.CategoryName,T2.Color FROM TABLE1 T1 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 on T1.ID  = T2.BrandID
        WHERE T1.BrandName LIKE '%Samsung%'
Example: 
SELECT T1.BrandName,T1.BrandID,T2.CategoryName,T2.Color FROM TABLE1 T1 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 on T1.ID  = T2.BrandID
        WHERE T1.BrandName LIKE '%[a-j]'
```